# Missing JAXB classes from XMLschema.xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I'm working on a xml schema resolver and I'm using JAXB with XMLSchema.xsd.
I experience problems with JAXB, because I don't get classes for all the top level elements. For example for

```
<xs:element name="maxLength" id="maxLength" type="xs:numFacet">
```

I do not get a class MaxLength or anything like that. Only NumFacet exists.

Anyone else experienced that and could please help me?

Cheers,
XLR

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember jaxb, the schema compiler xjc creates classes for each complex type of the schema given. Thus, if you like to have a class MaxLength you should add a complex type declaration to your schema:

`<xs:complexType name="MaxLength">

 <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:int"/>

 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="MyMaxLength" type="MaxLength"/>`

You should now get a class *MaxLength* with a member variable *value* of type integer.

Comment: Seriously? I am using the original XMLSchema.xsd, which I do not want to manipulate. In addition as you see there already is an element with a type ;)

Comment: Sure. Doesn't your example say: hey, there is an instance of type numFacet which I call maxLength. In Java, this would be: NumFacet maxLength = new NumFacet(); no need for another class. what should a class MaxLength look like, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

JAXB will not generate a class for anything that already has a type, and neither do you need one.

If you unmarshal a global element like your `maxLength` element, then JAXB will return you a JAXBElement wrapping the `NumFacet` type. Something like this:

```
JAXBElement<?> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(myStream);
NumFacet value = (NumFacet) root.getValue();
```

There are other methods on JAXBElement to find out what the element name was, etc.